# How to adjust my 4 inch screen background to not cut off in 3.5 inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1, not using auto layout and doing my work in Storyboards. I've created my game on the 4 inch screen simulator and today i successfully fit all my 4 inch screen images to fit in the 3.5 inch screen. The only thing that still cuts off is the background. The background is not a `UIImageView`. I programmatically coded the background to be in the game.

For background i'm using...

```
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"]];
```

To make images fit where I need them in 3.5 inch screen from 4 inch screen simulator i'm using...

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==480.0f)
    {

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BG.png"]];
    }

}
```

I tried the above code to fit the background for 3.5 inch screen but the bottom is still cut off. I also used the above code to perfectly fit everything from 4 inch screen to 3.5 inch screen so i don't know why it won't work for the programmed background. Please help.

Comment: Why you are not using UIImageView instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that code in `viewDidLoad` it's not going to work. Move it to `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` and see.